# Rendering of a quote of another discourse post

Tags: discourse

I've created a WordpressComment class that checks if the comment is referencing another comment. If it does it adds a reference in the same pattern as the UI

```
def body(lookup)
  quoted = nil
  parent = nil
  if parent_import_id != nil then
    parent_id = lookup::post_id_from_imported_post_id(parent_import_id)
    parent = Post.where(id:parent_id).first
    if parent != nil then
      user = User.where(id:parent.user_id).first
      @parent_user_name = user.username_lower
      quoted = "[quoted=\"#{parent_user_name}, post:#{parent.post_number}, topic:#{parent.topic_id}\"]<br/><br/>#{parent.cooked}<br/>[/quote]<br/>"
    end
  end
  return "#{quoted}#{content}<p /><p />#{author}<p />#{author_url}".gsub(/\\n/,'<br/>').strip[0...32000]
end
```

It inserts the right link .. but it's not rendering correctly.

It looks something like this

[quote="{username}, post:{post_id}, topic:topic_id"]
... quoted text ...
[/quote]

I researched [search?q=quoting another post #dev](https://meta.discourse.org/search?q=quoting%20another%20post%20%23dev%20)

Interestingly I found a few posts with the same quoting issue.

How do you add a quote from another post in post.raw so that it gets rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheers and thanks, to Florian at meta.discousre.org

The issue was I had quoted instead of quote, and there has to be a line break at the end of the quote block.

Fixing the typo and inserting the line break worked!

```
def body(lookup)
  quoted = nil
  parent = nil
  if parent_import_id != nil then
    parent_id = lookup::post_id_from_imported_post_id(parent_import_id)
    parent = Post.where(id:parent_id).first
    if parent != nil then
      user = User.where(id:parent.user_id).first
      @parent_user_name = user.username_lower
      quoted = "[quote=\"#{parent_user_name}, post:#{parent.post_number}, topic:#{parent.topic_id}\"]<br/><br/>#{parent.cooked}<br/>[/quote]\n<br/>"
    end
  end
  return "#{quoted}#{content}<p /><p />#{author}<p />#{author_url}".gsub(/\\n/,'<br/>').strip[0...32000]
end
```